# Equivalent of cURL for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, curl

Is there a cURL library for Ruby?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) and

```
  open("http://...", :http_basic_authentication=>[user, password])
```

accessing sites/pages/resources that require HTTP authentication.

Comment: Honestly, if I see that a library uses open-uri internally, I don't use that library.  It's a deeply flawed library built on top of a deeply flawed URI parser.  It's fine for usage in IRB and that's it.

Comment: @Sporkmonger: Well, that's what we have— what do you suggest, raw Net::HTTP?

Comment: Use Net::HTTP or Patron or Curb or any of the other libraries mentioned in the other answers.  How this answer got voted up or accepted is beyond me.

Comment: Well maybe because open-uri is part of standard library?

Comment: Net::HTTP and open-uri are both notoriously bad in how they do http.

Comment: What if you need to save a session in cookie you receive in respond to login request and you need to pass this cookie every time you fetch data ?

Answer (score 92):

[Curb](https://taf2.github.io/curb/) and [Curl::Multi](https://github.com/kball/curl_multi.rb/) provide cURL bindings for Ruby.

Answer (score 36):

If you like it less low-level, there is also [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), which is built on top of Curl::Multi.

Answer (score 9):

[Curb-fu](http://github.com/gdi/curb-fu/tree/master) is a wrapper around Curb which in turn uses libcurl. What does Curb-fu offer over Curb? Just a lot of syntactic sugar - but that can be often what you need.

Answer (score 8):

[HTTP clients](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) is a good page to help you make decisions about the various clients.

Answer (score 7):

You might also have a look at [Rest-Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

Answer (score 6):

the [`eat`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/eat) gem is a "replacement" for OpenURI, so you need to install the gem `eat` in the first place

```
$ gem install eat
```

Now you can use it

```
require 'eat'
eat('http://yahoo.com')                 #=> String
eat('/home/seamus/foo.txt')             #=> String
eat('file:///home/seamus/foo.txt')      #=> String
```

It uses [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) under the hood. It also has some options:

```
eat('http://yahoo.com', :timeout => 10)                   # timeout after 10 seconds
eat('http://yahoo.com', :limit => 1024)                   # only read the first 1024 chars
eat('https://yahoo.com', :openssl_verify_mode => 'none')  # don't bother verifying SSL certificate
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  `require': cannot load such file -- eat (LoadError)

Answer (score 6):

If you know how to write your request as a `curl` command, there is an online tool that can turn it into ruby (2.0+) code: [curl-to-ruby](https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/)

Currently, it knows the following options: `-d/--data`, `-H/--header`, `-I/--head`, `-u/--user`, `--url`, and `-X/--request`. It is [open to contributions](https://github.com/jhawthorn/curl-to-ruby).

Answer (score 5):

There's also [Mechanize](https://rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize), which is a very high-level web scraping client that uses Nokogiri for HTML parsing.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little program I wrote to get some files with.

```
base = "http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/code/samples/tutthreads_"

for i in 1..50

  url = "#{ base }#{ i }.rb"
  file = "tutthreads_#{i}.rb"

  File.open(file, 'w') do |f|   
    system "curl -o #{f.path} #{url}"
  end

end
```

I know it could be a little more eloquent but it serves it purpose. Check it out. I just cobbled it together today because I got tired of going to each URL to get the code for the book that was not included in the source download.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a more recent answer, [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) is another Ruby library that uses libcurl, supports parallel threads and lots of the curl goodies. I use HTTPClient and Typhoeus for any non-trivial apps.

Answer (score 2):

To state the maybe-too-obvious, tick marks execute shell code in Ruby as well. Provided your Ruby code is running in a shell that has `curl`:

```
puts `curl http://www.google.com?q=hello`
```

or

```
result = `
  curl -X POST https://www.myurl.com/users \
  -d "name=pat" \
  -d "age=21"
` 
puts result
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice **minimal reproducible example** to copy/paste into your rails console:

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = "https://www.example.com"
html_file = URI.open(url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)
doc.css("h1").text
# => "Example Domain"
```