# How to get the HTML source of a webpage in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby

In browsers such as Firefox or Safari, with a website open, I can right click the page, and select something like: "View Page Source" or "View Source." This shows the HTML source for the page.

In Ruby, is there a function (maybe a library) that allows me to store this HTML source as a variable? Something like this:

```
source = view_source(http://stackoverflow.com)
```

where source would be this text:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Stack Overflow</title>
etc
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

```
require 'net/http'

source = Net::HTTP.get('stackoverflow.com', '/index.html')
```

Answer (score 18):

```
require "open-uri"
source = open(url){ |f| f.read }
```

UPD: Ruby >=1.9 allows syntax

```
require "open-uri"
source = open(url, &:read)
```

UPD: Ruby >=3.0 [demands](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15893#note-4) syntax

```
require "open-uri"
source = URI(url).open(&:read)
```

Comment: Even shorter: `source = open(url).read`

Comment: @Mark Thomas, it will not close connection.

Comment: Both of these will close the connection?

Comment: And still the thing where it needs to be `URI.open...` (fwiw, I'm on Ruby 3.1.0).

Comment: As observed by Mark Thomas and Matt Rose, the simple `.read` is shorter. With neither `.read` nor `, &:read)` nor `{|f| f.read}` nor any invocation of `.close` was I able to observe connections being closed right away (but then, my way of testing is to simply keep watching the output of `netstat` while opening 100 connections).

Comment: In contrast, `u=URI.parse('https://domain.tld:443/');c=Net::HTTP.new(u.host,u.port);c.use_ssl=true;c.get(u.request_uri)` opens and closes in one fell swoop. So perhaps using `URI#open` should be discouraged??

Answer (score 13):

```
require 'open-uri'
source = open(url).read
```

short, simple, sweet.

Comment: Will not close connection.

Comment: And I had to do `URI.open...`.

Comment: @Sixtyfive I suppose it's some recent Ruby stdlib change.

Comment: "Suggested edit queue is full" ... mod?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, like this:

```
require 'open-uri'

open('http://stackoverflow.com') do |file|
    #use the source Eric
    #e.g. file.each_line { |line| puts line }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the builtin [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html):

```
>> require 'net/http'
>> Net::HTTP.get 'stackoverflow.com', '/'
```

Or one of the several libraries suggested in "[Equivalent of cURL for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929652/equivalent-of-curl-for-ruby)".

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://google.com/')

puts page.body
```

you can then do a lot of other cool stuff with mechanize as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you might be interested in is [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). It is an HTML, XML, etc. parser that is very easy to use. Their front page has some example code that should get you started and see if it's right for what you need.

Comment: Nokogiri has nothing to do with retrieving a page, it only parses the page once it's been retrieved by a HTTP client or read from a file. It's a very important distinction.

Comment: @theTinMan - Indeed, this was more informational and perhaps should have been posted as a comment rather than an answer. My assumption was that after getting the HTML, the OP would want to do something with it :-)

Comment: We hope they'd want to do something more with it, rather than clog a network and bog down a CPU.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) installed, you could simply:

```
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
html = `curl #{url}`
```

If you want to use pure Ruby, look at the [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) library:

```
require 'net/http'
stack = Net::HTTP.new 'stackoverflow.com'
# ...later...
page = '/questions/4217223/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-webpage-in-ruby'
html = stack.get(page).body
```