# rails - how to make a GET request to a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello there I'm hoping this problem is a fairly simple one as I am relatively new to rails development. I am trying to make a get request to a URL.For Example on success on certain action I need to make a get request to a URL with my parameters

> http://abc.com/xyz.php?to=<%user.number%>&sender=TESTHC&message="MY MESSAGE"!

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581075/how-make-a-http-get-request-using-ruby-on-rails.

Comment: Sorry @CodeGnome havent seen that I have got the answer you need-- `code`require 'net/http' and then  `code` Net::HTTP::Get.new("url")

Answer (score 1):

read this http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html you will get good examples to refer.

Comment: thanks for answering @abhas but I am a new bee to rails so I didn't know where to put that in my routes and how to pass that into an action..

Answer (score 1):

This might help. There is a gem called [Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday). It is used to make http request. Here is an example usage:

**Build a connection**

```
conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://sushi.com') do |builder|
  builder.use Faraday::Request::UrlEncoded  # convert request params as "www-form-urlencoded"
  builder.use Faraday::Response::Logger     # log the request to STDOUT
  builder.use Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp     # make http requests with Net::HTTP

  # or, use shortcuts:
  builder.request  :url_encoded
  builder.response :logger
  builder.adapter  :net_http
end
```

**Make your Get request**

```
conn.get '/nigiri', { :name => 'Maguro' } # GET /nigiri?name=Maguro
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question, as posed, has nothing to do with Rails or routes. If you want to make an HTTP request, whether from a Rails controller or a standalone Ruby program, you can use a standard library such as [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html).

As an example:

```
require 'open-uri'
to, sender, message = 12345, 'foo', 'bar'
uri='http://abc.com/xyz.php?to=%d&sender=%s&message="%s"' % [to, sender, message]
open(uri).readlines
```