# Reading a webcal URL in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar, webcal

I am trying to parse a webcal link

```
webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/b.php?uid=13301632&key=asdgagaweg
```

in a Ruby on Rails app so I can customize the event entries. I have looked into both [RiCal](http://ri-cal.rubyforge.org/) and [icalendar](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) but neither show any support for reading a calendar feed (webcal://).

Are there any Rails libraries that support parsing webcal addresses? If not, how should I go about creating my own parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

webcal is just an unofficial URI scheme for accessing icalendar documents. You can get the calendar using http and parse it using one of several icalendar plugins:

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://www.facebook.com/ical/b.php?uid=13301632&key=asdgagaweg')
calendar = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

For alternative ways to perform the http get request:
[How make a HTTP request using Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581075/how-make-a-http-get-request-using-ruby-on-rails)

Then parse the response using your favourite plug-in:

[icalendar](http://icalendar.rubyforge.org/rdoc/):

```
cal = icalendar.parse(calendar).first
```

[vPim](http://vpim.rubyforge.org/):

```
cal = Vpim::Icalendar.decode(calendar).first
```

[ri_cal](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyredrick/ri_cal/RiCal):

```
cal = RiCal.parse_string(calendar).first
```