# Send call to a web API instead of local database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

How can I have API methods in a rails app receive user input, then make calls to a web API (e.g., Twitter) instead of querying the local database within the rails app? I also would like to store the user query in the local rails database. So the workflow would be like so:

- User enters a query term in the app
- Store the query term in the local database
- Send out a call to a web API (e.g., Twitter API) - retrieve the data
- Present data from the web API

I understand how to call web APIs in Ruby, but not sure where in a Rails app I put methods to do so, and how they are linked to user input.

I am somewhat new to Rails. I have looked at many tutorials, etc., but can't seem to find any help on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gems like

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

https://github.com/taf2/curb

or you can do it manually

[How make a HTTP request using Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581075/how-make-a-http-get-request-using-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Right, I understand how to define a function to call a web API, but then how is this linked in to user input?  I assume the method to call the web API gets put into a controller file?

Comment: Before starting any serious stuff in rails I suggest you to understand the scaffolding. It covers all of the rails basic stuff.
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html