# Get in Rails - receive get requests with params and redirect them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, parameters, get

How do I - in Rails - receive a get request from one website (url), then save the parameters, and generate a new url of another website, with other parameters (calculated/ from db), and redirect to it?

I have no problem with the steps in the middle (e.g. saving to db, receiving parameters). The main question is how do I receive a get request, AND send a get request in Rails.

I saw according to the following question: [How make a HTTP request using Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581075/how-make-a-http-get-request-using-ruby-on-rails) that I can use the `Net::HTTP` class. However it seems there that they focus on requesting from another website some data, while here we are receiving hits from some website and want to redirect to another one.

My question is: 
1. How do I save as a variable the url that the person arrived from (there is a paramater I need from there)?
2. How do I redirect the user to the new url at the end of the steps (saving, parsing new url, etc)?
3. Where do I perform these two main actions? In the controller? That is my instinct, however, doesn't the view hold the relevant url? where is the relevant index url people are referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps I am not understanding well the question, but, assuming that your static_pages#index is receiving the get request:

in your StaticPagesController:

```
def index
  incoming_url = request.referer # this catch the incoming url, including its params
  incoming_url_params = URI(incoming_url).query # this returns an string with the incoming url params
  new_url = do_something_with_the_url_and_its_params_internally(incoming_url, incoming_url_params)
  redirect_to new_url
end
```

So as an example somebody coming from `http://www.wikipedia.org?lang=es`, that will be the `incoming_url` and `incoming_url_params` would be "lang=es"

Hope that helps

Comment: Okay, yes, I think this is it! So I do not need to touch the view at all then? All the logic here in the controller (and in the model for that matter for the db parts). Correct? Thanks

Comment: Wait, another question - how do I retrieve the :url_to_be_redirected ? there are parameters in the url I need to use

Comment: Right, the view will not even seen by nobody

Comment: @LucyWeatherford I have edited the answer to show how to parse the incoming url