# how to close IE9 browser session that has a popup message "Do you want to open or save file" displayed

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

on my web application, after clicking a download button, **a popup message with content "Do you want to open or save "abc.txt" from this site?" with 3 buttons ("Open", "Save" & "Cancel")** will be displayed at the bottom of page.

I'm trying to **close/quit this browser session with below codes**:

```
@driver.execute_script "window.onbeforeunload = function(e){};"
@driver.quit
```

However, the browser is NOT (but should be) closed. I'm working with **Selenium Ruby Webdriver**. Please guide me a way to resolve this problem. Thanks so much.

Note that with the above codes, I'm able to close IE9 browser that has the popup message "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered many not be saved" with "Leave Page" and "Stay on Page" buttons successfully. But, codes do NOT work in case the popup message with content "Do you want to open or save "abc.txt" from this site?" with 3 buttons ("Open", "Save" & "Cancel") displayed.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver has no control over these types of "Save file" dialog prompts.

Please peruse this article on this subject (note, his examples are in Java, but they can all be ported easily and with less code in Ruby). http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Thus, I would recommend not even clicking the link in question and trying to deal with the dialog. Instead, grab the `href` value and initiate a `Net::HTTP` request to it like this SO response shows you how to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581116/1221475 . You can then check the file for correct contents and such using standard Ruby and file parsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack by [Dave Haefner](http://elementalselenium.com/tips). It is written for Java/Selenium combination, but you can easily convert it to Ruby syntax.

If you don't care if a file was downloaded or not and you want to confirm only that a file can be downloaded, you can use an HTTP request. Instead of downloading the file you'll receive the header information for the file which contains things like the content type and length. With this information, you can confirm the file is you expect.

```
    String link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("download-link-element")).getAttribute("href");

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpHead request = new HttpHead(link);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    String contentType = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Type").getValue();
    int contentLength = Integer.parseInt(response.getFirstHeader("Content-Length").getValue());

    assertThat(contentType, is("application/octet-stream"));
    assertThat(contentLength, is(not(0)));
```