# API token in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Python and moving into rails. I have login python file:

```
resp = session.post('https://dummy.dummy.com/api/v1/sessions', data={
    "username": "email",
    "password": "######"
})
```

this will return API Token and from that we will get roles.
How do I use this login in ruby on rails ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make a HTTP request using Ruby on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581075/how-make-a-http-request-using-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: In my terminal i will run activate.sh which has "export API_TOKEN=`python ~/login.py`;" So basically login.py will return my api token. I need to implement this in ruby on rails. Since I am migrating from python to ROR. Also I am new to ROR

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `net/http` for your purpose. Have a look at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post