# Screen scraping and proxies using Ruby

Tags: ajax, proxy, screen-scraping, erb

I know there are several screen scraping threads on here but none of the answers quite satisfied me.

I am trying to scrape the HTML from an external web page using javascript. I am using $.ajax and everything should work fine. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my.url/path",
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        var myVar = $.get(url);
        alert(myVar);
    }
});
```

The only problem is that it is looking for the specified url within my web server. How do I use a proxy to get to an external web page?

Comment: It depends on the type of server you're using and what server-side language you want to use.

Comment: I'm using embedded ruby for the server

Comment: I've edited your title so it gets a more appropriate audience.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the site I'm trying to access can't be accessed from the server. Thus, I am attempting to access it via javascript because the clients that are accessing the server can access the other webpage. In fact, I am already accessing the external webpage from my ruby server but that isn't working for my application, so I need to try to do it in the javascript.

Comment: The Same Origin Policy prevents you from making AJAX calls to other domains, so that won't work.

Comment: Could I get the json using jsonp?

Comment: *IF* the external server *explicitly* allow you to.

Comment: Well, I've got it. The json doesn't quite give me _exactly_ what I want, but it's a start. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Due to Cross Site Scripting restrictions, you're going to have to pass the desired URL to a page on your server that will query the URL in question from serverside, and then return the results to you. Take a look at the thread below and the incorporate that into your application and have it return the source when that page is hit by your AJAX function.

[How to get the HTML source of a webpage in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217223/how-to-get-the-html-source-of-a-webpage-in-ruby)

Using a GET request is going to the be easiest way to transfer the URL of the page you want to fetch your server so you'll be able to call something like:

```
$.ajax("fetchPage.rb" + encodeURI(http://www.google.com))
```

Because you can't access the side in question directly from the server, you're going to have to pipe the serverside script through a proxy for the request to work, which really kind of depends on your setup. Taking a look at the Proxy class in Ruby:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-Proxy