# ruby and curl: skipping invalid pages

Tags: ruby, curl

I am building a script to parse multiple page titles. Thanks to another question in stack I have now this working bit

```
curl = %x(curl http://odin.1.ai)
simian = curl.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)[1]
puts simian
```

but if you try the same where a page has no title for example

```
 curl = %x(curl http://zales.1.ai)
```

it dies with undefined method for nill class as it has no title ....
I can't check if curl is nil as it is not in this case (it contains another line)

Do you have any solution to have this working even if the title is not present and move to the next page to check ? I would appreciate if we stick to this code as I did try other solutions with nokogiri and uri (Nokogiri::HTML(open("http:/.....") but this is not working either as subdomains like byname_meee.1.ai do not work with the default open-uri so I am thankful if we can stick to this code that uses curl.

## UPDATE

I realize that I probably left out some specific cases that are ought to be clarified. This is for parsing 300-400 pages. In the first run I have noticed at least two cases where nokogiri, hpricot but even the more basic open-uri do not work

1) open-uri simply fails in a simple domain with _
like http://levant_alejandro.1.ai this is a valid domain and works with curl but not with open_uri or nokogiri using open_uri

2)The second case if a page has no title like 
http://zales.1.ai

3) Third is a page with an image and no valid HTML like http://voldemortas.1.ai/

A fourth case would be a page that has nothing but an internal server error or passenger/rack error.

The first three cases can be sorted with this solution (thanks to Havenwood in #ruby IRC channel)

```
curl = %x(curl http://voldemortas.1.ai/)
begin
   simian = curl.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)[1]
rescue NoMethodError
   simian = "" # curl was nil?    
rescue ArguementError
   simian = "" # not html?
end
puts simian
```

Now I am aware that this is not elegant nor optimal.

## REPHRASED QUESTION

Do you have  better way to achieve the same  with nokogiri or another gem that includes these cases (no title or no HTML valid page or even 404 page) ? Given that the pages I am parsing have a fairly simple title structure, is the above solution suitable ? For the sake of knowledge it would be useful to know why using an extra gem for the parsing like nokogiri would be better option (note: I try to have few gem dependencies as often and over time they tend to break).

Comment: it's the output of `match` which is `nil`, not the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check for the match before accessing it. If `curl.match` is `nil`, the you can't access the grouping:

```
curl = %x(curl http://odin.1.ai)
simian = curl.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)
simian &&= simian[1] # only access the matched group if available
puts simian
```

Do heed *the Tin Man's* advice and use Nokogiri. Your regexp is really only suitable for a brittle solution -- it fails when the `title` element is spread over multiple lines.

## Update

If you really don't want to use an HTML parser and if you *promise* this is for a quick script, you can use OpenURI (wrapper around net/http) in the standard library. It's at least a little cleaner than parsing `curl` output.

```
require 'open-uri'

def extract_title_content(line)
  title = line.match(%r{<title>(.*)</title>})
  title &&= title[1]
end

def extract_title_from(uri)
  title = nil

  open(uri) do |page|
    page.lines.each do |line|
      return title if title = extract_title_content(line)
    end
  end
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
  STDERR.puts "ERROR: Could not download #{uri} (#{e})"
end

puts extract_title_from 'http://odin.1.ai'
```

Comment: I have rephrased the question for clarity but your solution is pretty close to the one I posted on the revised question.

Comment: @devnull: If this is a quick job, I'd go for just parsing the title manually. If you need to do this for more general web pages, then you'll get the immense benefit of *not* having to write regexps for edge-case`TITLE` elements. A rule of thumb I try to follow: use an HTML parser if the job takes more than 15 min to do OR if your code will be maintained by someone else. If the last statement is false...see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're making it much to hard on yourself.

Nokogiri doesn't care where you get the HTML, it just wants the body of the document. You can use Curb, Open-URI, a raw Net::HTTP connection, and it'll parse the content returned.

Try Curb:

```
require 'curb'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(Curl.get('http://http://odin.1.ai').body_str)
doc.at('title').text
=> "Welcome to Dotgeek.org * 1.ai"
```

If you don't know whether you'll have a `<title>` tag, then don't try to do it all at once:

```
title = doc.at('title')
next if (!title)
puts title.text
```

Take a look at "[equivalent of curl for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929652/equivalent-of-curl-for-ruby?rq=1)" for more ideas.

Comment: tin Man: many thanks for this. I hate to sound such a pain but this does not work if the page users non HTML in the index e.g. http://voldemortas.1.ai so curl it is more appropriate in my humble opinion (and I do mean %x(curl...). I am just a bit puzzled on why would it be a better solution to include 2 gems (one for curl which shouldn't be needed and one for nokogiri which is certainly very appropriate for more complex parsing..I would love to use it but it simply doesn't work in some cases as the one mentioned above.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to look for a title tag in anything but HTML (or maybe XML). So why not just check the returned content type before trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

What you're really looking for, it seems, is a way to skip non-HTML responses. That's much easier with a curl wrapper like curb, like the Tin Man suggested, than dropping to the shell and using curl there:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > require 'curb'
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :002 > response = Curl.get('http://odin.1.ai')
 => #<Curl::Easy http://odin.1.ai?> 
1.9.3p125 :003 > response.content_type
 => "text/html" 
1.9.3p125 :004 > response = Curl.get('http://voldemortas.1.ai')
 => #<Curl::Easy http://voldemortas.1.ai?> 
1.9.3p125 :005 > response.content_type
 => "image/png" 
1.9.3p125 :006 >
```

So your code could look something like this:

```
response = Curl.get(url)
if response.content_type == "text/html" # or more fuzzy: =~ /text/
  match = response.body_str.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/)
  title = match && match[1] 
  # or use Nokogiri for heavier lifting
end
```

No more exceptions
puts simian