# What is the Ruby equivalent to this curl request?

Tags: ruby, curl, faraday

I'm tring to post to an api. This example from the docs works in curl:

```
curl -k -w %{http_code} -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -u user:pass --data-binary @filename https://server/url/here
```

This is what I have tried with faraday:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'faraday'
require 'pp'

conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://server/url/here' , :ssl => {:verify => false} ) do |faraday|
   faraday.response :logger
   faraday.basic_auth('user', 'pass')
   faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter
 end

data = File.read('teste.txt')

res=conn.post '/' , data
pp res
```

It posts, I receive a 200 code but something goes wrong. The response is the server's login page.

Is curl -u equivalent to basic auth?

Comment: duplicated with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929652/equivalent-of-curl-for-ruby?rq=1

Comment: I cant see where it is duplicated.

Comment: sorry, forget it. Could you provide the actual API URL?

Comment: According to the curl man page: "-u, --user <user:password> Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.", so it should be equivalent to HTTP Basic Auth. Note however, that the site's login page has nothing to do with HTTP Basic Auth, it is a separate layer of authentication.

Answer (score 5):

That looks right, the only difference is possibly the content-type in the header, this should work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'faraday'
require 'pp'

conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'https://server/url/here' , :ssl => {:verify => false} ) do |faraday|
   faraday.response :logger
   faraday.basic_auth('user', 'pass')
   faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter
 end

data = File.read('teste.txt')

res = conn.post do |req|
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
  req.body = data
end

pp res
```

Answer (score 1):

I know your question concerns the Faraday gem but here is how I would have done it using the 'rest-client' gem, maybe this can help:

```
response = RestClient.post "https://user:pass@server/url/here", data,
                           :content_type => 'text/plain'
```