# curl command equivalent in ruby

Tags: ruby, http, curl, http-post, postdata

I have a curl command that works well, but I need to automate this in a ruby script,

curl cmd:

```
curl -u usrname:pwd -X POST --data "del=false&val=100" http://localhost:1111/sample/path
```

I wrote the following code:

```
uri = URI::HTTPS.build(:host => "localhost", :port => 1111)
uri.path = URI.escape("/sample/path")
client = Net::HTTP.new("localhost", "1111")
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, {"User-Agent" => "UA"})
req.set_form_data({"del" => "false", "val" => "100"})
req.basic_auth("usrname", "pwd")
res = client.request(req)
```

The above code is working, I had a encoded url that I was passing to URI.escape, that made me post this question about bad response. Foud the issue and fixed it :)

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/929697/1088818) delivers what you're asking for.

Answer (score 28):

**THE BEST & EASY SOLUTION!!**

1. Copy your CURL code.
2. Go to this [page](https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/).
3. Paste your CURL code.
4. Be happy.

I tested this solution this page its amazing.

Comment: This is a really good solution, its a applicable solution for this especific question and other group of similars questions.

Ill be happy if know the reason for negative votes for my answer.

Comment: Note: Does not work with all `curl` arguments. No `-F` for example.

Answer (score 9):

you can execute the curl command directly from ruby

```
usrname = "username"
pwd = "pwd"
val = 100
del= false
http_path = "http://localhost:1111/sample/path"
puts `curl -u #{usrname}:#{pwd} -X POST --data "del=#{del}&val=#{va}" #{http_path}`
```

and the back ticks will execute the system curl

Comment: I am looking to do a http post in ruby instead of making to do a system call for curl

Comment: curl is platform dependent. also, you shouldn't suggest command line solutions when the language itself has a solution

Comment: That's an absolute and much like everything else in programming its entirely dependent on context and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb#http-post-form)

```
c = Curl::Easy.new

c.http_auth_types = :basic
c.username = 'usrname'
c.password = 'pwd'

c.http_post("http://localhost:1111/sample/path", "del=false&val=100")
```

Comment: use this documentation to find the equivalents of the parameters you need https://www.rubydoc.info/github/taf2/curb/Curl/Easy