# Rails 4 - Launchy gem doesn't work on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am looking for a way to easily open an external url in my rails 4 controller.

Right now, I have this in my controller:

```
  def download_file
    require 'Launchy'
    surveys = FluidsurveysSurvey.where("name like '%#{params[:string_to_search_for]}%'")
    surveys.each do |survey|
      Launchy.open("https://fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/surveys/#{survey.fs_id}/csv/?_created_at>#{params[:start_date]}&_created_at<#{params[:end_date]}")
    end
    redirect_to responses_path
  end
```

Locally, this works fine. I can run my server in development, and it will open each url in separate tab as it should.

However, when I push to Heroku, the code doesn't work. It errors with this:

`LoadError (cannot load such file -- Launchy):`

What can I do to either use Launchy in production, or open an external url via another method?

Comment: How you expect this to work on heroku exactly? Post your Gemfile as well

Comment: Maybe you'd be better switching to [open-URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929652/equivalent-of-curl-for-ruby)